# Refreshing Calendar Control that gets value from Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, refresh

I have a calendar control in my project, and I want to set its (SelectedDate) based on Textbox value. It works fine, but the problem is that the Calendar Control stays on the current month page (same month we are in). However, the selected value is updated based on the textbox, and the date is highlighted when I move the calendar to that date (Textbox value date).

Calendar in Default.aspx

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" CssClass="table"  runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
```

Code behind:

```
  Calendar1.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting **VisibleDate** too:

```
Calendar1.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text);
Calendar1.VisibleDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text);
```

Refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.visibledate.aspx)